# omp_get_thread_num() returns bugged number?

Tags: c++, c, openmp, intel

The codes are of thousands of lines, so I cannot pasted them, but the function flow looks somehow like:

```
void Func_1(double * x, int nx, NUM_THREADS)
{
  omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
 //...
};



void Func_2(double *y, int ny, NUM_THREADS)
{ 

 omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
   //...
  #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
      int threadID=omp_get_thread_num();
       //...
     };

 };



int main (void)    
{

//...
  Func_1(x, nx, NUM_THREADS);
  Func_2(y, ny, NUM_THREADS);

//...

};
```

So basically I get two functions, each call omp_set_num_threads within the function, the problem is, now if I build the program, then the `threadID` returned in the runtime is total nonsense, the `threadID` becomes some very large int number like 16113312... that far exceeding `NUM_THREADS`.

Have anyone experienced similiar problems with Open MP(Intel ICC 13.0)?

Btw, a possible hint is, However I build `Func_1` and `Func_2` in seperate DLL library and ask the `main()` to call these functions from the DLL instead of build them all-together with the `main()`, then all works fine.

Comment: I doubt the function itself returns gibberish. Rather check your code for out-of-bounds array accesses that could possibly lead to local stack variables being overwritten.

Comment: I agree with Hristo. I don't think `omp_get_thread_num()` is a problem. 16113312 = 0xF5DEA0, possibly corrupted by overflow.

Comment: How are you determining the value?  Are you using `printf` by any chance?  If you do that from inside the parallel region, you're bound to have your output corrupted unless you serialize access.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced this error, when I was trying to set different number of threads than what  is needed to export. i.e. before starting your applications you will have to

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS  4
```

Check if the number of threads in this location is different than what you use in omp_set_num_threads();

Hope this helps.